# What are software requirements for a Windows Mobile smartphone to run .NET apps?

Tags: .net, smartphone, windows-mobile-6.5

What software do I need on a Windows Mobile smartphone (apart from the OS, that is) to install a cab file that is created for a .NET Compact Framework application with database operations?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need Microsoft ActiveSync

Comment: But that's required on the desktop, right? Why would I need ActiveSync on the client device?

Comment: Yes, On your client device you do not need that.

Comment: the client device does need an activesync client, but i think they all have that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the device requires .NET Compact 3.5 (for example). If You'd like to debug from desktop then ActiveSync is required.

Comment: What about SQL Server compact edition? Require that too, right?

Comment: If You are planning to use SQL - then it is required. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13kw2t64(v=vs.90).aspx